# Missing dependency in package.json

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, lerna

I'm creating a new monorepo project with lerna but I keep getting this error:

> Missing dependency in package.json

when creating a react app in packages. Is there a way I can solve it? I have attached a screenshot of the procedures have followed.

[image]

Comment: Try to run `npm install` to resolve any missing dependencies?

Comment: At what stage should I run this command?

Comment: At any stage, it basically installs dependencies if they are missing.

Answer (score -1):

Actually you have the package.json created  inside the e-commerce directory so you would need to run the create react app command from e-commerce directory instead of packages directory